# Get dropdown value which is dynamically created

Tags: c#, gridview

I want to store the value of `dropdown` which is dynamically created in dynamically template field.

How can I access the value of selected `dropdown` value on the submit button.

I use below

```
public class AddTemplateToGridView : ITemplate
{
    ListItemType _type;
    string _colName;

    public AddTemplateToGridView ( ListItemType type, string colname )
    {
        _type = type;
        _colName = colname;
    }

    void ITemplate.InstantiateIn ( System.Web.UI.Control container )
    {
        switch ( _type )
        {
            case ListItemType.Item:

                DropDownList ht = new DropDownList();
                ht.ID = "ht" + _colName;
                ht.Width = 50;
                ht.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select", "Select"));
                ht.Items.Add(new ListItem("P", "P"));
                ht.Items.Add(new ListItem("A", "A"));
                ht.Items.Add(new ListItem("H", "H"));
                ht.Items.Add(new ListItem("S", "S"));
                ht.Items.Add(new ListItem("L", "L"));
                ht.DataBinding += new EventHandler(ht_DataBinding);
                container.Controls.Add(ht);
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a my custom code:
 Create a windows form "test" and on its load write the following code:

```
        private void test_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Values");


            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Sagar","Sagar_Value" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Hari", "Hari_Value" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Ram", "Ram_Value" });

            LoadDynamicCombo(comboBox1, dt);

            dt.Clear();
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "one", "one" });

            LoadDynamicCombo(comboBox2, dt);
        }


        public void LoadDynamicCombo(ComboBox _cmb,DataTable dt )
        {
            _cmb.DataSource = dt.Copy();
            _cmb.DisplayMember = "Name";
            _cmb.ValueMember = "Values";

        }
```

Datatable with columns "Name" and "Values" passed to function "LoadDynamicCombo" accepts argument of your combo and datatable. Combo1 is filled with first set of datas whereas Combo2 is filled with second set of datas..